# warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. when using antd DropDown

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using antd `"antd": "^5.3.0",` dropdown in react `"react": "^18.2.0",` project like this:

```
 <Dropdown className="user-menu" menu={{ items }} trigger={['click']} placement="topRight">
                        <Avatar size={40} >Me</Avatar>
                    </Dropdown>
```

this is how the `items` define:

```
const items: MenuProps['items'] = [
        {
            key: '2',
            onClick: doLoginOut,
            label: (
                <a className="user-action-item">
                    Logout
                </a>
            )
        }, {
            key: '3',
            onClick: showUserProfile,
            label: (
                <a className="user-action-item">
                    Control
                </a>
            )
        }]
```

when I click the Dropdown, the console log shows warning like this:

```
act_devtools_backend.js:2655 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of DomWrapper which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node
    at li
    at InternalItem (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:61499:25)
    at InternalRawItem (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:61914:52)
    at LegacyMenuItem (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:58128:90)
    at InternalMenuItem (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:58160:21)
    at MenuItem (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:58283:24)
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:13493:24
    at DomWrapper (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:62627:90)
    at SingleObserver (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:62669:24)
    at ResizeObserver (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:62796:24)
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:14112:34
    at Tooltip (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:65601:32)
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:36299:16
    at MenuItem (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:26531:5)
    at ul
    at Overflow (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:61610:32)
    at InheritableContextProvider (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:59036:23)
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:57624:27
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:26912:55
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:26836:64
    at NoCompactStyle (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:30953:5)
    at OverrideProvider (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:26627:7)
    at div
    at Align (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:53701:23)
    at DomWrapper (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:60319:90)
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:60030:32
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:65977:23
    at div
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:66201:22
    at http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:68299:25
    at Trigger (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:66506:92)
    at Dropdown (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:53996:28)
    at Dropdown (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:22860:42)
    at div
    at nav
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Chat (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:1368:86)
    at ConnectFunction (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:95790:114)
    at div
    at Home (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:1223:88)
    at ConnectFunction (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:95790:114)
    at RenderedRoute (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:99574:5)
    at RenderErrorBoundary (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:99525:5)
    at Routes (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:100064:5)
    at Router (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:100002:15)
    at RouterProvider (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:99848:5)
    at Provider (http://dev-ai.poemhub.top/static/js/bundle.js:95520:5)
overrideMethod @ react_devtools_backend.js:2655
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
findHostInstanceWithWarning @ react-dom.development.js:28762
findDOMNode @ react-dom.development.js:29645
findDOMNode @ findDOMNode.js:17
getDom @ index.js:31
(anonymous) @ index.js:34
imperativeHandleEffect @ react-dom.development.js:17131
commitHookEffectListMount @ react-dom.development.js:23150
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23268
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24688
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24674
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24612
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26823
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26682
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26117
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:25651
```

why did this happen? what should I do to avoid the warning? I already tried to upgrade the antd to `"antd": "^5.4.2"`, still could not work.

Comment: Wrap Avatar with any html element i.e. div. This will remove the warning

Comment: I tried what you say, but still could not work.

Comment: Can you create codesanbox?

Comment: Wrapping works, can you please tell me the reason? @MuhammadNoumanRafique

Comment: First antd dropdown need to detect when node is clicked so it can open the popover. Second antd dropdown needs to detect the position of the current node so it can set the position of popover.